# How do I compile wxWidgets with the same options as the package as the repository?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, compiling, package-management, configure

I am compiling wxWidgets as a pre-step to compiling the newest version of pgAdmin3 since there isn't a deb version in the repository that supports version postgres 9.2.  I am having troubles and eliminating possibilities.

The default package has a version of wxWidgets that works with pgAdmin3.  I want to install the same options of this package.

When I type:

```
./configure --help
```

I get a whole host of options.  How do I find out the options used to compile the default package version so I can match its functionality.

I have tried to use:

```
--enable-debug --enable-button --enable-ect.
```

but after 10 or so options I worry that I will miss something (and according to the output of the other compile I am) or I will add something that is conflicting.

Is there a list of options that the repository is using for wxWidgets.

Using Mint Nadia 14/Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simple way,

First use `apt-get source XXX` to get the source code,

When extraction completes, enter the folder, i.e XXX-version, and check the `debian/control` file, normally you would see a `DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS +=` line, that's where you should look at.

Comment: apt-get source did not work,  could be because it is an outside package.  Downloaded the deb from the repositories.  The file existed, I checked for DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS wasn't there.  Thanks.

Comment: @DarkSheep the deb file is the binary package, you need to get the source package

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any special options to build wxWidgets for pgAdmin. So just build it with default options.

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% sure wxWidgets does not use special command line on Ubuntu for compile config. But make sure you check any missing development libraries dependency.